# 'ChromeDriver' object has no attribute 'switch_to'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I was facing an issue where the chromedriver was unable to find element by id eventhough the values were correct.
So I added the below step

```
#switch into iframe
driver.switch_to.frame("frameid")
```

This is the error message now

```
'ChromeDriver' object has no attribute 'switch_to'
 chromedriver=81.0.4044.69 chromeversion=81.0.4044.92
```

Is it because of the older version of chrome being used?

Answer (score -1):

As per the [Selenium Python Changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ed7d29eb07ae9544954fc9cb84a8417a80f600fe/py/CHANGES#L796):

```
Selenium 2.41

* Support for Firefox 28
* deprecating switch_to_* in favour of driver.switch_to.*
```

So you were pretty right analyzing the error which was because of older version of chromedriver/chrome combo being used.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.3.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v103.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=103.0.5060.53/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=103.0* (as per [chromedriver=102.0.5005.61 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/103.0.5060.53/notes.txt)).

Comment: Updated everything as stated above could still see the error

Comment: I also added switch_to_frame instead of switch_to.frame . The error message this time -"Chrome driver has no styribute switch_to_frame"

Comment: Close your IDE and reboot the system and then execute the test.